# Ruby Radio buttons and hidden field not showing up with form_with url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, radio-button, hidden-field

I'm trying to make a form where I have a dropdown to display all my stores, and also have three radio buttons for the user to indicate a preferred time period. Currently, none of them are showing up.

Eventually, I'll be sending the data of this form to a calculate_stores method in one of my controllers.

Here is what I have for the form.

```
<%= form_with url: calculate_stores_path, method: :get, local: true do |f|%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :store_id %>
    <%= f.radio_button :set_time_span, '2 weeks', :value => 14 %>
    <%= f.radio_button  :set_time_span, '1 month', :value => 30 %>
    <%= f.radio_button :set_time_span, 'custom', :value => 0 %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you verify if the form is getting generated in view source of your page in browser?

Comment: Yes, I Experimented with a date picker and that showed up L fine.

Answer (score 1):

[radio_button](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button) helper method is used for accessing a specific attribute on **an object** which you dont have in your form.

Properly [radio_button_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag) suites your need better?

```
<%= form_with url: calculate_stores_path, method: :get, local: true do |f|%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'store_id' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'set_time_span', '2 weeks', :value => 14 %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'set_time_span', '1 month', :value => 30 %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'set_time_span', 'custom', :value => 0 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @turtlefish12, try to change the `:set_time_span` to `'set_time_span'`